# Get the size of all Azure SQL Databases

Tags: azure-sql-database, reporting

I need to produce a report showing all our Azure SQL Databases with their size.  The databases are split among many resource groups in several subscriptions.

I can get the information for a single instance, or even for all DBs in a resource group, but I have too many RGs to make that a workable solution, and I cannot find a way of getting the information for a whole subscription, or whole tenancy.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up patching a few bits of PowerShell together from various sources.  It was pretty slow running, but did the job.

```
#Connect-AzAccount

#$OutData = @()
$IgnoreDB = @('master', 'SSISDB')
$Subs = @('Subscription1','Subscription2', 'Subscription3', 'Subscription4')

$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
Foreach ($Subscription in $Subscriptions)
{

    if ($Subscription.Name -in $Subs)
    {

    #Setting context so the script will be executed within the subscriptions scope
    Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $Subscription.Name | Set-AzContext

    $AzSqlServer = Get-AzSqlServer

        Foreach ($server in $AzSqlServer)
        {
            $SQLDatabase = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ServerName $server.ServerName -ResourceGroupName $server.ResourceGroupName -WarningAction silentlyContinue | Where-Object { $_.DatabaseName -notin $IgnoreDB }
            Foreach ($database in $SQLDatabase)
            {
                $db_resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceId $database.ResourceId

                # Database maximum storage size
#                $db_MaximumStorageSize = $database.MaxSizeBytes / 1GB

                # Database used space
                $db_metric_storage = $db_resource | Get-AzMetric -MetricName 'storage' -WarningAction silentlyContinue
                $db_UsedSpace = $db_metric_storage.Data.Maximum | Select-Object -Last 1
                $db_UsedSpace = [math]::Round($db_UsedSpace / 1GB, 2)

                # Database used space procentage
#                $db_metric_storage_percent = $db_resource | Get-AzMetric -MetricName 'storage_percent' -WarningAction silentlyContinue
#                $db_UsedSpacePercentage = $db_metric_storage_percent.Data.Maximum | Select-Object -Last 1

                # Database allocated space
#                $db_metric_allocated_data_storage = $db_resource | Get-AzMetric -MetricName 'allocated_data_storage' -WarningAction silentlyContinue
#                $db_AllocatedSpace = $db_metric_allocated_data_storage.Data.Average | Select-Object -Last 1
#                $db_AllocatedSpace = [math]::Round($db_AllocatedSpace / 1GB, 2) 

                # Database VCore
#                $db_VCoreMin = $db.MinimumCapacity
#                $db_VCoreMax = $db.Capacity

#                $Report = New-Object PSObject
#                $Report | Add-Member -Name "ServerName" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $server.ServerName
#                $Report | Add-Member -Name "DatabaseName" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $database.DatabaseName
#                $Report | Add-Member -Name "UsedSpace" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $db_UsedSpace
#                $Report | Add-Member -Name "UsedSpaceProcentage" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $db_UsedSpacePercentage
#                $Report | Add-Member -Name "AllocatedSpace" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $db_AllocatedSpace
#                $Report | Add-Member -Name "MaximumStorageSize" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $db_MaximumStorageSize
#                $Report | Add-Member -Name "MinvCores" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $db_VCoreMin
#                $Report | Add-Member -Name "MaxvCores" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $db_VCoreMax
#                $OutData += $Report

                write-host $Subscription.Name ',' $server.ServerName ',' $database.DatabaseName ',' $db_UsedSpace

            }
        }
#        $OutData | Out-GridView
 }
}
```